# Android google maps custom layout

Tags: android, view, maps

For my question (below), this is my current layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/verylightgrey" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location_banner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:background="#9e0039" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/verylightgrey" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/location_directions"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:src="@drawable/directions" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/map_satellite" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/map_street" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="ladidadiomagadi"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to enable some click listeners on parts that are not mapview.

Is it even possible to do that in an activity that extends `Mapactivity` because the only way I have been able to do this is by moving my views to the menu options.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ,You can implement Onclick listener on MapActivity.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to move your `com.google.android.maps.MapView` part above all its sibling views.

Comment: Does not work. If i do that it seems that the part behind mapview is ommited and my code cant find the id of location_banner.

Comment: For me, the parts above `com.google.android.maps.MapView` (I mean, in this layout file) can not been seen. And if you exchange your positions of views in layout file, a **clean** should be done.